# Androidアプリ内課金に用いるIabHelper.javaの不具合と、その解決策・回避策について

Tags: android, アプリ内課金

Androidのアプリ内課金を実現するために、よく利用するものとして挙げられているtrivialdrivesampleのutil群ですが、その中にあるIabHelperには、端末によって起動時にNullPointerExceptionが発生してしまう問題が指摘されています。

参考

- [Billing API v3 IabHelper NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456434/billing-api-v3-iabhelper-nullpointerexception)
- [IAB startSetup NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626870/iab-startsetup-nullpointerexception)

以前、別の問題が起きていた頃はGoogleが修正版をアップデートしていましたが、この問題は現在も残っているというか、2013年末以降いっさい更新が行われていない状態です。

すでに日本国内でもLG系の端末の一部で、それらしいエラー報告を確認しています。
現在アプリ内課金を実装しているデベロッパーの皆様は、IabHelper等を使わずに自前実装されているのでしょうか？それとも、他に上記の問題等を解決している別のソースコード等を利用されているのでしょうか？

ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

新しいライブラリに移行しています。
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/118
こちらの Issue のやりとりが参考になるかと思います。